# How to get javascript function to return selected database entries

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

I am creating a web directory of organisations which displays the organisations within the selected county using an xml database.

For testing purposes I have only set it up to display the organisation names and counties at the moment but when I have a county name in the javascript marked with // <---------- I get only that county's organisations.  How do I get a cross-browser solution for the option list in the html to select the county?

There will be more than one organisation per county in the fully working version and the web addresses in the xml data will need to be outputted as hyperlinks which is why I am extracting each child node one at a time instead of all the children in one go. The idea is still work in progress and the output will eventually be in separate divs for each organisation.

**My html**

```
<form>
Select your choice of county:
<select onchange="DisplayData(this)">
  <option>---</option>
  <option>UK</option>
  <option>Hampshire</option>
  <option>Surrey</option>
  <option>Berkshire</option>
</select>
</form>
```

**My javascript**

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
try {xhttp.responseType="msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp;
}


var x=loadXMLDoc("data.xml");
var xml=x.responseXML;
function DisplayData(option)
{
name="/data/record[county[contains(., 'Hampshire')]]/name";        //<---------
// name="/data/record[county[contains(., option)]]/name";          DISPLAYS ALL COUNTIES
// name="/data/record[county[contains(., $option)]]/name";         DISPLAYS ALL COUNTIES
county="/data/record[county[contains(., 'Hampshire')]]/county";    //<---------

// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType=="msxml-document")
{
xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage","XPath");
nodes1=xml.selectNodes(name);
nodes2=xml.selectNodes(county);
for (i=0;i<nodes1.length;i++)
  {
  document.write("<b>Name:</b> " + nodes1[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("<b>County:</b> " + nodes2[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("<br>");
  }
}

// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
var nodes1=xml.evaluate(name, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var nodes2=xml.evaluate(county, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var result1=nodes1.iterateNext();
var result2=nodes2.iterateNext();

while (result1)
  {
  document.write("<b>Name:</b> " + result1.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("<b>County:</b> " + result2.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("<br>");
  result1=nodes1.iterateNext();
  result2=nodes2.iterateNext();
  }
}
}
</script>
```

**My test data.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
    <record>
        <name>Hampshire Organisation</name>
        <town>Basingstoke</town>
        <county>Hampshire</county>
        <tele>01234 567890</tele>
        <web>www.hampshireorg.com</web>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Surrey Organisation</name>
        <town>Woking</town>
        <county>Surrey</county>
        <tele>01234 567890</tele>
        <web>www.surreyorg.com</web>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Berkshire Organisation</name>
        <town>Reading</town>
        <county>Berkshire</county>
        <tele>01234 567890</tele>
        <web>www.berkshireorg.com</web>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Nationwide Organisation</name>
        <town>London</town>
        <county>UK</county>
        <tele>01234 567890</tele>
        <web>www.nationwideorg.com</web>
    </record>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem

`<select onchange="DisplayData(this)">`
needed to be changed to 
`<select onchange="DisplayData(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">`

This allows the `option` variable within the javascript to work when altering
`name="/data/record[county[contains(., 'Hampshire')]]/name";`
 to `name='/data//record[contains(./county, "' + option + '")]/name';` for example as suggested by slamborne within his answer

**and** it works cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that `<select onchange="DisplayData(this)">` is returning the select element, not the option selected.
The selected option can be obtained like so: `option.selectedOptions[0]` and `option.selectedOptions[0].innerText` can be used to get the text.

Another serious issue is the XPath query that contains the option string. The string is parsed as a literal, so it's searching for "option", not the data contained in the option variable. It should look like this: `name="/data/record[county[contains(., " + option + ")]]/name";`

---

Assuming each data/record entry is unique, you don't need to use a while loop on those nodes because you will only have one result. I don't use XPath but I assume you could use a while loop to iterate through the childNodes if you needed to.

Below is my version of DisplayData without the browser checking.
Since the data exists together as children of the one node, I only use one query. This is ideal because if you need to pass the record data around, it's self contained.

And here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6meAVXXcvwitS9nTWUzm?p=preview).

```
function DisplayData(option) {

  var selectedOption = option.selectedOptions[0].innerText;

  var xpath = '/data//record[contains(./county, "' + selectedOption + '")]';
  var result = xml.evaluate(xpath, xml.documentElement, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);

  if (result.singleNodeValue !== null && result.singleNodeValue.children.length > 0){

    var el = document.getElementById('results');
    el.innerHTML = '';

    var data = result.singleNodeValue.children;
    for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++){
      el.innerHTML += '<li>' + data[i].textContent + '</li>';
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help which has given me some useful information, however I need this to work cross browser and yet what you put into plunker works fine in chrome but not in internet explorer or firefox. Plus, sorry I didn't mention it before, but I do need a while loop as there will be more than one organisation per county and the web addresses in the xml data will need to be outputted as hyperlinks which is why I was extracting each child node one at a time instead of all the children in one go. The idea is still work in progress and the output will eventually be in separate divs for each org